# Make DropDownList using SelectList in ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu

I've been trying to make a drop down list using the `SelectList` class.
What I mean by that is **NOT** the following.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int SelectedValue { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<int> ValueList { get; set; }
}
```

There are many examples on how to get that to work, and I have. I'm looking to use the said `SelectList` class in the view model.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public SelectList ValueList { get; set; }
}
```

The advantage of that, I suspect, is when passing the result to the controller and `ModelState` is invalid, you can just do `return View(model)` and everything will be as it was.
If you have it split up you'll have to fetch the list of items again, set the selected value somehow. Too inconvenient!

Is there a reason why no one is using the SelectList in the view model? I'd appreciate a working example if possible :)

Thank you.

Comment: Snæbjørn - one immediate reason for not using a `SelectList` in the viewModel is that it requires a reference to the `System.Web.Mvc` lib. this therefore places a burden on any 'other' client apps using the viewModel. However, depending on your architecture, that may be a moot point

Comment: Valid point, but I'm using domain models and view models (AutoMapper) so it's not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have a scenario like this working in my project. I am using MVC3, but I believe this would apply.

In my ViewModel I have a property defined as follows:

```
        private List<SelectListItemWithAttributes> pLeadDispositions = null;
    public List<SelectListItemWithAttributes> LeadDispositions {
        get {
            var LeadDispositionItems = (
                from c in db.GetLeadDispositionList(1, 1000)
                where c.AccountTypeID == this.AccountTypeID
                select new SelectListItemWithAttributes() { Text = c.Title, Value = c.ID.ToString(), HtmlAttributes = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "data-callback", c.RequiresCallback.ToString().ToLower() } } } ).ToList()
            ;

            LeadDispositionItems.Insert(0, new SelectListItemWithAttributes() { Text = "-- Select --", Value = "", HtmlAttributes = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "data-callback", "false" } } });

            return LeadDispositionItems;
        }
    }
```

SelectListItemWithAttributes is just a sub-class of SelectListItem that I am using, so you can just replace that with SelectListItem and modify the parameter list.
GetLeadDispositionList is a stored procedure that gets the data I need from the database.

In my view is looks like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListWithItemAttributesFor(m => m.LeadDispositionID, Model.LeadDispositions)
```

DropDownListWithItemAttributesFor is a sub-class of DropDownListFor that I am using for my project, so just substiture DropDownListFor

I know this isn't exactly what you are looking for, but maybe it will get you pointed in the right direction.

I hope this helps.